# How to check syntax correctness of a C code programmatically?

Tags: c, gcc, syntax

I'm working on a software plagiarism detection method for C source files. To do that, I made a program to simplify the syntax of source codes, like making all variable names same and making all loop types same. Obviously, I can't do this on the codes which have not proper syntax (therefore cannot be compiled).

There is a GCC command to see syntax problems on a C source code: `gcc -c -fsyntax-only assignment1.c`. This command prints `assignment1.c` code with some weird lines and syntax problems (if exists). But I need like a boolean output, just specify if the code written properly or not. Is there a command for this? Or how can I use `-fsyntax-only` command for this purpose? (By the way, I don't want to compile codes, all I need is check their syntaxes.)

edit: I think I'm misunderstood. I need to read C source files and then check their syntaxes programmatically. So I should use the output of command `gcc -c -fsyntax-only assignment1.c` in the program I created.

Comment: Aren't there already tools that do this? Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I think the exit code of `gcc` should tell you if it has any problems.

Comment: `gcc -fsyntax-only file.c 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: @Barmar: I think I'm misunderstood. I need to read C source files and then check their syntaxes programmatically. So I should use the output of command `gcc -c -fsyntax-only assignment1.c` in the program I created.

Comment: I understood fine. Aren't there already code plagiarism checkers, why are you writing one yourself.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, of course there are lots of. This is my term project. So I need to reinvent the wheel (with my own way) :(

Comment: so what is wrong with `gcc -fsyntax-only file.c 2>/dev/null` ? seems you already  had the answer...

Comment: @OznOg: Thank you, I tried it in terminal screen but it didn't print anything.

Comment: in shell the return value is not printed, it is available in `$?` if you want a display thing, try: `gcc -fsyntax-only file.c 2>/dev/null && echo true || echo false`

Comment: More verbosely: `if gcc -c -fsyntax-only file.c > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo Good; else echo bad; fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC’s `-fsyntax-only` flag can be used to test whether an input file is syntactically valid without producing any output file. The return value is set depending on whether the input was valid.

Thus, the following works in sh/Bash:

```sh
input=file.c

if gcc -c -fsyntax-only "$input" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "$input is valid C code"
else
    echo "$input is invalid"
fi
```

The output redirection is added to suppress syntax error messages.